# Htaccess alias or rewrite confusion

Tags: .htaccess, alias

i searched but i couldn't manage the situation.

Site has bad structure so i put new framework's index file in directory under document root, called "web".

So, is there a htaccess solution to use url

```
www.anysite.com/alias-name/(*)
www.anysite.com/another-alias-name/(*)
```

Points to

```
www.anysite.com/web/(*)
```

While old structure links still work as usual.

I tried rewrite rule but it changes url that is not desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this htaccess code :

```
Alias /web/ /alias-name/
Alias /web/ /another-alias-name/
```

Comment: throw 500 internal error. but thank you anyway i create alias httpd.conf it works.